# A nomination for the Medal of (editing) Honor

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, users

> I hereby nominate [eldarerathis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390989/eldarerathis) to receive the **Medal of** (editing) **Honor** for patience, bravery and editing beyond the call of duty.
>
> At approximately 4:30 AM (UCT) on Tuesday March 8th eldarerathis went to the aid of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228230/net-trouble-when-using-doubles), which was pinned down under heavy fire.  Crippled with badly formatted code, incomprehensible wording and a complete lack of punctuation it would not have lasted long if it wasn't for the quick thinking and editing abilities of eldarerathis.
>
> Thanks to eldarerathis the question is now reasonably likely to receive an answer.

Seriously, some people go out of their way trying to salvage otherwise completely incomprehensible questions.  If I could I would get these people medals (as long as it didn't cost more than about £1.50 including postage).

Comment: Stunning job.  That's one happy customer that will come back for more.  Yay.

Comment: Way to help recognize the extra effort!

Comment: He deserves the "Telepathic" badge for that, for sure...

Comment: It's a pity we can't up-vote edits separate from the question :)

Comment: Actually, I kind of like this idea. Community-voted badges!

Answer (score 20):

Lrert expLaIN me SOMETNg LOLZ .... Bd QUston h0rstc no w0rky 0.0001 
After UPvt crp qn

mohr crap  2 flw mohr wrk 4 EVrone ....,,, do we rally waant ths poisen keep askng THE question?????????????

Comment: `QUston h0rstc no w0rky 0.0001` means?

Answer (score 8):

People like [eldarerathis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390989/eldarerathis) and [Lord Torgamus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) (a.k.a. [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713)) definitely deserve to be recognized for going beyond the call of duty (some may say beyond the call of *sanity!*) to make Stack Overflow a better place. To recognize these brave souls, wouldn't it be cool to have *community-awarded* badges? For example:

> http://kevinx.net/labs/php/badge.php?txt=Medal%20of%20Editing%20Honor&c=s Nominated by ten community members for a significant editing contribution to Stack Overflow.

Whenever someone on Stack Overflow noticed a significant edit that salvaged an otherwise incomprehensible post, he or she could then *nominate* the author for this badge. Nominations could decay just like close votes, and the badge would be awarded once ten people seconded the nomination.

I think that this would be a fun way for the community to acknowledge people who have gone out of their way to make Stack Overflow a better place.

---

#### 2012/02/24

Were this badge to exist, I would definitely nominate [Lord Torgamus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) and [animuson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) for stepping up to the challenge and fixing [this train wreck of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8681448/7). I think [the results](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8681448/10) [speak for themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9437846/1).

Comment: Good idea - I have no idea how you would stop this from being abused though

Comment: @Kragen Yeah, I thought about that too. I suppose you would need to have a nomination-fraud script similar to the voting-fraud script to ensure that the same people are not repeatedly nominating the same person for this badge.

Answer (score 6):

You think *that* was heroic? You young'uns, you ain't seen nothing yet...

> At 1847 hours GMT on the 23<sup>rd</sup> of November 2010, Lord [Lord Torgamus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus) (aka [Popular Demand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713)) [swung into action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4223398/revisions#spacer-37ff53d2-0aca-41a8-a536-73ee82ac3a8a) in the train wreck that was "[RE: How can Google be so fast? Is there a VERY important detail missing on the web about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223398/re-how-can-google-be-so-fast-is-there-a-very-important-detail-missing-on-the-we)".
>
> Armed with only deft fingers, a comfortable keyboard and a very good command of both the English language and Markdown, he hacked and slashed his way through tons of unnecessary bolding, poorly phrased sentences and incomprehensible paragraphs to create something that... stinks slightly less.
>
> [image: Screenshot of the diff of the edit]
>
> Even though he attempted the impossible, and failed*, we salute you Lord Lord Torgamus, for your bravery and commitment to making Stack Overflow a slightly happier place for Markdown Nazis like me to live in.

---

*<sup>Bill had already closed the question a day before that; the chances of this god awful question getting reopened even with the edit is still nil.</sup>

Comment: Revision note: "minor formatting fixes and retag"  Somebody's modest.  :)

Comment: [Popular Demand](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand), did you edit the question praising your editing heroics? You have a editing fever man, seek help!